# Jumping to a new page in PageView.builder after the additon of a new page doesn't seem to work as expected [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a simple layout that consists of a *PageView.builder* widget that contains several pages. The contents of each page are simple, they contain a *Container* and a *Text* widget inside of it.

**cards** is a *List* of type *String* and the *Pageview.builder* widget has an *itemCount* that's based on the length of this List. The value of the *Text* in each page is assigned using this List.

```
List<String> cards = [];
```

Now, whenever I add a new value to **cards** List, a variable **newPage** is used to store the last index position in the List after that element has been added.
After doing this, *setState(() {});* is called so that the UI along with the PageView update to reflect the changes made in the List.

The PageView widget does reflect the changes and a new page does get added to it.
However, the problem arises when I try to jump to newly added page right after calling setState.
The error indicates that the index value that *jumpToPage* is trying to use is out of range in the PageView

```
    cards.add("New card");
    newPage = cards.length - 1;
    setState(() {});
    card_PageController.jumpToPage(newPage);
```

So, after trying to figure something out, I added a *Timer* after the setState, so that the framework get's some time to properly update the UI elements.
I'm using a small value of 50 milliseconds in the *Timer* function and jumping to the new page after the timer gets over.

```
    cards.add("New card");
    newPage = cards.length - 1;
    setState(() {});
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
      card_PageController.jumpToPage(newPage);
    })
```

The addition of a *Timer* seems to solve the problem and there were no errors after it's addition. However, I'm not sure if this is the right way of tackling this problem.

I'd like to know as to why is this happening, as shouldn't calling *jumpToPage* directly after setState work without the use of a *Timer*?

Also, does setState infact take some time to finish updating the UI, even though it isn't async, and that due to this reason the referenced index is invalid? And could this problem have been tackled in a better way?

Comment: Could you share more of your code? I understand you wanted to be thorough with your explanation, but sometimes less is more, and despite understanding mostly your problem, I think we would benefit from seeing a larger scope of your code and less descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared I can't detect an issue. Especially because I've reproduced what you said you wanted to achieve and it works without issue. Take a look at the code below:

```
class PageCards extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageCardsState createState() => _PageCardsState();
}

class _PageCardsState extends State<PageCards> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();
  List<String> cards = [
    'page 0',
    'page 1',
    'page 2',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageController,
            itemCount: cards.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Center(
                child: Text(cards[index]),
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Add page'),
          onPressed: () => addCard(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void addCard(){
    setState(() {
      cards.add('page ${cards.length}');
    });
    _pageController.jumpToPage(cards.length - 1);
  }
}
```